# Missing return Statement of multiple IFs

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, return

Where is the problem? If I use a variable it works just fine, but I am missing something.

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
  if (str.length() > 2){
    if(str.startsWith("xyz")){
        return true;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 2; i++){
            if(str.substring(i, i + 3).equals("xyz") && !str.substring(i - 1, i).equals(".")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
  } else {
  return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've got two conditions. The compiler can't check that they can't *both* be false.

Comment: remove the last `else {
  return false;
  }` and add `return false;` as the last statement in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition needs a return statement as the code inside for loop may not be reachable.

```
else {
                for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
                    if (str.substring(i, i + 3).equals("xyz") && !str.substring(i - 1, i).equals(".")) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler will not evaluate the conditions to determine if one of `if` condition and an `else if` condition will be guaranteed to run.

Without the conditions, the compiler see the possibility of neither condition being `true`, and in that case, nothing is returned.  There are not `return` statements past the `else if`.  This occurs even if we see that logically one of them will be `true`.

Just turn your `else if` into an `else` to satisfy the compiler.

```
else {
    return false;
}
```

Now the compiler will see that there is a `return` statement in all possible execution paths.

In these cases, sometimes I comment out the condition to let readers know the real intent.

```
else // if (str.length() < 3)
{
    return false;
}
```

**Update:**

Something similar is occurring inside the `for` loop.  The compiler won't assume that at least one iteration of a `for` loop will occur.  If the `for` loop body is never entered, then the `else` block ends, and the body of the outer `if` block ends without a `return` statement`.

You must provide a `return` statement after the `for` loop, in case the `for` loop is never entered.

Comment: this doesn`t fix the issue

Comment: It looks like I found one of the two related issues.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because it might be possible  that none of your  `outer if` condition succeed , So ***Compiler*** is making sure that your program doesn't get stuck into the function  , by throwing  the `missing return statement` error

So try this way :

```
if(condition){
return false;
}
elseif(condition){
return true;
}
return false; <--- Now compiler is assured that function will return something
```

Assuming the return type is ***boolean***

Comment: How might it be possible for the outer if to be unsuccessful when the condition (the length of the string) is always checked in my opinion?

Comment: You knew it So do I , but java's little innocent `compiler` doesn't and he just make sure that at Runtime Noone's get in trouble !!! and Why Not it will surely be false when the length of String is less than `2`

Answer (score 0):

Now it is compiling:

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 3){
  return false;
  } else {
    if(str.startsWith("xyz")){
        return true;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 2; i++){
            if(str.substring(i, i + 3).equals("xyz") && !str.substring(i - 1, i).equals(".")) {
                return true;
            } else {
            }
        }
        return false;
    } 
  }
}
```